# Javascript window.open menubar always showing

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, show, menubar

I have a question regarding the JavaScript window.open function, I have the requirement that in the new window the menu bar of the browser appears always, I am using internet explorer 9, and when I add the option menubar=1 in the window.open function the menu bar appears hidden in the new window, I need to press "ALT" key to make the menu bar appear and when I click in any other place of the window the menu bar hides again, is there a way using JavaScript or other type of code to make the menubar appear unhidden all the time in the new window?, here is the window.open call that I am using:

```
 window.open("Destination.aspx","Title","menubar=1",true);
```

The new window is for open a pdf file inside it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happen if you try `menubar=yes` ?

Comment: I tried with 'yes' value too but the result was the same, the menubar is activated but is hidden in the new window